# Schopenhauer's monism

Tags: schopenhauer

When Schopenhauer talks about his monistic thing in itself is he talking about a 'will' that goes around destroying and wanting right?

But what about the dead stuff they can't 'will' right?

So is there even a physical characteristic(essential to being 'will') in Schopenhauer's world view?What are the interpretations?

Comment: No, there is no such a characteristic. Everything in the world has the Will aspect in Schopenhauer's metaphysics, including dead and inanimate stuff. Even rocks "will". See [SEP, The World as Will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schopenhauer/#4).

Comment: Isn't Schopenhauer's Will another word for Hindu's Brahman ? If so, the notion of Will is really closer to the self-determination of "God", nothing is then either willing or not except in the sense where they act on the nature of God to whom they belong. So when anything wills, it follows its nature which part of the Brahman (which is following its nature).

Comment: @Gloserio The difference is that Schopenhauer's Will is neither conscious nor rational nor even "spiritual" in any Hinduist or Buddhist sense, it is a blind base urge.

Comment: I'm not sure this description would be enough to distinguish Will from Brahman. It would depend on defiinitions. Brahman is not 'spiritual' and may be described as neither rational nor conscious (or not in the way we usually use these words). I reckon N came close to Brahman but would agree he didn't make it all the way. certainly the word 'urge' seems inappropriate, but it might mean no more than following its nature. Just trying to be kind to S.   .

Comment: @Conifold: indeed, however, Brahman's consciousness does not mean it can alter its will, it's probably to be taken as awareness. Not to say I am an expert in either Hinduism or Schopenhauer.

Comment: @PeterJ: that's where I was trying to go, its some version of Brahman without the exaltation.

Comment: It's a simplification to say that Schopenhauer's Will is "another word for Brahman". There's a knot of interpretational issues there. A decent source: https://philarchive.org/archive/MAHSVVv1

Comment: @transitionsynthesis - You're right, of course. But S can be seen as struggling towards this idea, Had he come closer he would not have used the word 'Will'.

Comment: @PeterJ I still don't see that as the right characterization. Schopenhauer used the word 'will' for principled reasons, not because he was unable to find a better alternative. Can't we just say there are two distinct concepts here with some interesting overlaps?

Comment: @transitionsynthesis - Sure. This issue is always going to be matter of opinion. But consider this statement by S about altruism and the unity of consciousness - "That experience, therefore, must be the metaphysical ground of ethics and consist simply in this: that one individual should recognise in another, himself in his own true being … Which is the recognition for which the basic formula is the standard Sanskrit expression, ‘Thou art that’, tat tvam asi.” This view requires Brahman as the foundational principle, albeit it may be given other names. . .

Comment: @PeterJ What you've pointed out is that Schopenhauer himself saw his project as continuous with (what he knew of) the Vedic ideas, though it's not clear he always interpreted them very rigorously. In any case, my point is that I think it's unfair to portray any differences between S's 'Will' and the 'Brahman' as merely a quantitative difference in degree, where Schopenhauer's concept just "falls short". There are, it seems to me, qualitative differences. I don't see its a  matter of opinion but rather as a matter of who has the superior exegetical account.

Comment: @transitionsynthesis - I'm not really disagreeing but suggesting that S was groping towards an understanding of the Vedas and of Brahman, and in some ways coming close. The fact that he didn't get all the way is shown by his use of the word 'Will'. One wouldn't read S for an explanation of the Upanishads or Brahman, for the reasons you give, but the connection is clear.